# Sendmail not working properly

Tags: 13.04, email, putty, sendmail, joomla

I wanted my joomla website to send emails, so for that I installed `sendmail`.
I tested it by using putty `sendmail emailadress@domain.com content of email` to check if it was working.

I made multiple attempts using that command and just one time it delivery the email to my address for my surprise.

Then I tested with the website.

Joomla website which is using sendmail service, it's actually working and sending the emails; but it us taking a long time to send the email.

For example posting on the forum: every time anyone posts on the forum it sends an email notification to the subscribers. It starts the `sendmail` service, and the website takes about 2 to 3 minutes to publish the post and send out the emails.

After that Joomla gives an error message

```
Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail
```

However the email it's actually sent.

Using "htop" I can see only 2 minutes after posting, the sendmail service it's started.

The website in question is  [www.gruenherzjaeger.de](http://www.gruenherzjaeger.de)

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I hope these link will solve your issue > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178723/upgraded-to-joomla-2-5-6-could-not-execute-usr-sbin-sendmail < > http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=707983 < > http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/showthread.php?t=53549

Answer (score 1):

After several try's and digging in google. Installed sendmail + postfix multiple times with no success, tried other alternatives and nothing as well.
Then I found [this tutorial](https://library.linode.com/email/exim/send-only-mta-ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin?format=print)

Installed `apt-get install exim4-daemon-light mailutils`

Configured it. And boom everything started working properly.

While I was playing around with postfix I noticed it was not running neither starting, and and when I ordered it to start

```
postfix start
```

It was outputting `fatal error: postfix failled to start`. I think that was why it would't work. Thanks for your attention anyways =)